# Laravel merge excluding the primary object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.6

My question is very basic. I'm aware that it was asked before. But those questions has the answers which used to work in Laravel 4 and I can't quite get it to work in Laravel 5.6.

I'm trying to merge these two:

```
$posts = Post::where('user_id', $user->user_id)->get();
$comments = Comment::where('user_id', $user->user_id)->get();
```

The method I tried is this:

```
$activities = $posts->merge($comments)->sortBy('created_at');
```

This gives me only `$comments` In previous questions this seem to work in most cases but not in mine.

Also, I know there is an option to do it like

```
$activities = array_merge($posts->toArray(), $comments->toArray());
```

But when I do that I'm no longer able to detect which model or table the object belongs to or can't use the relationships.

I'm open to any solution with that, but I would love the ones where I can still use my relationships.

> Laravel 5.6

Comment: By the way, can I add a function into user model and have two models belonging them? Cuz what I'm trying to do is to show the user recent activities in the profile. If user can have `$comments` and `$posts` inside `activities()` function, than I can loop through them right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`merge()` replaces the `$posts` with `$comments` when they have the same primary key.

Use the base collection's `merge()`, it just appends `$comments` after `$posts`:

```
$activities = $posts->toBase()->merge($comments)->sortBy('created_at');
```

Comment: well that throws ***Trying to get property of non-object*** when I do `@foreach($activities as $activitiy) {{ $activitiy->content }} @endforeach`

Comment: I'm sorry my bad, It's actually working. Gonn do some tests and come back